# SVG fill styling not working on ios browsers

Tags: html, ios, css, svg

I have created a seating plan, and I want to highlight a specific seat with a different background and text color.

However the text color *fill:#ffffff* does not work on IOS devices (tested on Safari and Chrome), the tick sign is dark instead of being white.

I am using the following CSS:

```
g.clicked circle.fill {fill:rgb(64,64,64) !important;}
g.clicked text {-webkit-appearance: none;-moz-appearance: none;appearance: none;-webkit-text-fill-color:#ffffff;-webkit-opacity:1; fill:#ffffff;}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j76vag4f/

Is it an issue with my code, or is it a browser-related bug? If the latter, is there a workaround?

Thank you.